# Function overloading ambiguous use - Xcode 12.5

Tags: swift, xcode, overloading, xcode12.5

When I am defining enum:

```
enum Test: CGFloat {
    case zero
}
```

and two functions that are similar to the following:

```
func test(_ param: CGFloat) { 
    print("param - \(param)") 
}

func test(_ param: Test) { 
    print("param - \(param.rawValue)") 
}
```

Issue when I'm trying to use them:

```
test(Test.zero) <- prints "param - 0"
test(.zero) <- error: ambiguous use of .zero
```

While I understand that compiler is clashing with two definitions of `.zero`, I'm trying to pinpoint where it was changed in release notes of Xcode 12.5. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction? As it seems it's working in 12.4.

Note:

It can be fixed by:

- Better design of the API;
- Using `@_disfavoredOverload` as per following [conversation](https://forums.swift.org/t/compiler-choosing-between-functions-with-no-parameters-vs-functions-with-default-parameters/23501/2).

Comment: Thank you @hoseinalialborzi, but it seems like the question that you posted is related to return type. Where my question is about the release notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly a secondary consequence of

> Implicit member expressions now support chains of member accesses. (57295228)

You might file a bug because existing code broke, but it has an edge case feel so perhaps it should never have worked. In any case I bet saying `Test.zero` speeds up compilation. This sort of type checking is complicated, as your forum link shows.

Comment: Also, the type checker is constantly evolving and doesn’t need a specific entry in the release notes.